# What is the difference between overlapping subproblems and optimal substructure?

Tags: dynamic-programming, overlapping

I understand the target approach for both the methods where Optimal Substructure calculates the optimal solution based on an input n while Overlapping Subproblems targets all the solutions for the range of input say from 1 to n.

For a problem like the [Rod Cutting Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cutting-a-rod-dp-13/). In this case while finding the optimal cut, do we consider each cut hence it can be considered as Overlapping Subproblem and work bottom-up. Or do we consider the optimal cut for a given input n and work top-down.

Hence, while they do deal with the optimality in the end, what are the exact differences between the two approaches.

I tried referring to this [Overlapping Subproblem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overlapping-subproblems-property-in-dynamic-programming-dp-1/), [Optimal Substructure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/optimal-substructure-property-in-dynamic-programming-dp-2/) and [this page as well](https://web.archive.org/web/20200123003901/http://anandabhisheksingh.me:80/optimal-substructure-overlapping-subproblems/).

On a side note as well, does this relate to the solving approaches of Tabulation(top-down) and Memoization(bottom-up)?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067523/optimal-substructure) makes a valid point but I'm hoping if it could be broken down easier.

Answer (score 10):

**To answer your main question**: overlapping subproblems and optimal substructure are both different concepts/properties, a problem that has both these properties or conditions being met can be solved via Dynamic Programming. To understand the difference between them, you actually need to understand what each of these term means in regards to Dynamic Programming.

> I understand the target approach for both the methods where Optimal Substructure calculates the optimal solution based on an input n while Overlapping Subproblems targets all the solutions for the range of input say from 1 to n.

This is a poorly worded statement. You need to familiarize yourself with the basics of Dynamic Programming. Hopefully following explanation will help you get started.

Let's start with defining what each of these terms, Optimal Substructure & Overlapping Subproblems, mean.

**Optimal Substructure**: If optimal solution to a problem, S, of size n can be calculated by **JUST** looking at optimal solution of a subproblem, s, with size < n and **NOT ALL** solutions to subproblem, **AND** it will also result in an optimal solution for problem S, then this problem S is considered to have optimal substructure.

**Example (Shortest Path Problem)**: consider a undirected graph with vertices a,b,c,d,e and edges (a,b), (a,e), (b,c), (c,d), (d,a) & (e,b) then shortest path between a & c is a -- b -- c and this problem can be broken down into finding shortest path between a & b and then shortest path between b & c and this will give us a valid solution. Note that we have two ways of reaching b from a:

- a -- b (Shortest path)
- a -- e -- b

Longest Path Problem does not have optimal substructure. Longest path between a & d is a -- e -- b -- c -- d, but sum of longest paths between a & c (a -- e -- b -- c) and c & d (c -- b -- e -- a -- d) won't give us a valid (non-repeating vertices) longest path between a & d.

**Overlapping Subproblems**: If you look at this diagram from the link you shared:

[image]

You can see that subproblem fib(1) is 'overlapping' across multiple branches and thus fib(5) has overlapping subproblems (fib(1), fib(2), etc).

> On a side note as well, does this relate to the solving approaches of Tabulation(top-down) and Memoization(bottom-up)?

This again is a poorly worded question. Top-down(recursive) and bottom-up(iterative) approaches are different ways of solving a DP problem using memoization. From the Wikipedia article of Memoization:

> In computing, memoization or memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

For the given fibonacci example, if we store fib(1) in a ***table*** after it was encountered the first time, we don't need to recompute it again when we see it next time. We can reuse the stored result and hence saving us lot of computations.

When we implement an iterative solution, "table" is usually an array (or array of arrays) and when we implement a recursive solution, "table" is usually a dynamic data structure, a hashmap (dictionary).

You can further read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065433/what-is-dynamic-programming) link for better understanding of these two approaches.

Comment: Do you know any example which has overlapping subproblems but not optimal substructure property? I am thinking that if a problem has overlapping subproblems, then we can just use dp without thinking about optimal substructure property. Is this right?